# Why is the matrix derivative of the trace of $AB$ with respect to $B$ not a constant, but $A^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, matrix-calculus, trace

Why is this true?

$$\frac{d}{dB} Tr[A B]= A^\top$$

Trace is the sum of the diagonal elements. So, I'm expecting a number, a matrix! What's going on here?

Example: Given matrix A with $m \times n$, and B with $n \times p$, in particular, we have the following,

$$A= 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}
\end{bmatrix}, 
B= 
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{11} & b_{12} \\
b_{21} & b_{22} \\
b_{31} & b_{32}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

To get the answer, we mulitply, take derivative, then, trace.

First, we mutiply,
$$AB= 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}b_{11} + a_{12}b_{21} + a_{13}b_{31} & a_{11}b_{11} + a_{12}b_{21} + a_{13}b_{31} \\
a_{21}b_{11} + a_{22}b_{21} + a_{23}b_{31} & a_{21}b_{12} + a_{22}b_{22} + a_{23}b_{32}
\end{bmatrix} $$

Second, we take derivative. Fact: $\frac{d}{dB} Tr[A B]=  Tr[A \frac{d}{dB}B]$, 
$$A\frac{d}{d B}= 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}+ a_{12} + a_{13} & a_{11} + a_{12} + a_{13} \\
a_{21} + a_{22}+ a_{23} & a_{21} + a_{22}b + a_{23}
\end{bmatrix} $$

Third, we take trace,
$$Tr\left[ A\frac{d}{d B}\right] = a_{11} + a_{12} + a_{13} + a_{21} + a_{22}b + a_{23} = k$$

The result is $\frac{d}{dB} Tr[A B] = k$, this a constant. Not the matrix $A^T$ as established in the first equation.

Comment: What is your definition of $\frac{d}{dB}$?

Comment: When $f(\mathbf x)$ is a real-valued function with vector input, $\nabla f(\mathbf x)$  is a vector. Vector in, vector out. What's so surprising when it is matrix in, matrix out? $df/dB$ is a matrix, because you need to know $df/db_{ij}$ for each $(i,j)$.

Comment: See page 3 of "https://web.stanford.edu/~jduchi/projects/matrix_prop.pdf"

Comment: @nmasanta yes, I’ve seen that, but still don’t understand why it’s not a constant. Trace of anything (derivatives or not), should be a constant. So, why do I get a matrix.

Comment: @JulianMejia I mean the derivative, I guess it’s also called gradient? Yes, page 3 of this is what I mean. https://web.stanford.edu/~jduchi/projects/matrix_prop.pdf

Comment: @user1551 but when you take the trace of a derivative matrix, don’t you get a sum? That’s what I don’t get. It’s not intuitive.

Comment: and how do you claim  "Trace of anything (derivatives or not), should be a constant" @user13985 Give us some reference in support of your claim

Comment: @nmasanta Isn’t trace just the diagonal elements of a matrix? Whether it’s derivative or not, it’s irrelevant. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Yes, trace of a matrix is  sum of the diagonal elements of a matrix. See the link I provide here, $$\frac{\partial tr(AB)}{\partial a_{ij}}=b_{ji}$$ Here if you differentiate with one of element of $A$, say $a_{ij}$, you will get one element of $B^T$, say $b_{ji}$. Thus when you differentiate with respect to matrix $A$ you will get $B^T$

Comment: @nmasanta yes, I’ve seen the link before posting. So, where did the trace go? Isn’t the same as without the trace, except the transpose part?

Comment: With out trace the element is $b_{ij}$ and after trace it is $b_{ji}$. Since differentiate gives us $b_{ji}$, so we got $B^T$. see the subscript of $b$

Comment: @nmasanta Why does taking the trace switch the indices from $b_{i,j}$ to $b_{j,i}$? Trace is the diagonal elements, which has nothing to do with off-diagonals.

Comment: Take  small matrices, say $2\times 2$, and apply the same procedure on it. Take care of the rule of matrix derivative. For this you can follow "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Derivatives_with_matrices"

Comment: Can you write up an answer? I don't get how the trace turned $b$ to $b^T$. Sorry for so many questions, and thanks for your patience. :)

Comment: @nmasanta In my mind, trace of anything results in a number. I just can’t accept the fact that I would end up with another matrix. $tr(X)=\sum x_{ii}$ X can be a derivative matrix or not, no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95111/discussion-between-nmasanta-and-user13985).

Comment: "Fact: $\frac{d}{dB} Tr[A B]=  Tr[A \frac{d}{dB}B]$" No, that is not a fact. That formula is not true. (You can see that it must be incorrect because the left hand side is a matrix whereas the right hand side is a scalar.)

Comment: @littleO Then $\frac{d}{dB}[tr AB]$ means fist calculate trace, then derivative, yes? If so, trace is a sum of multiple terms, which came from the diagonal, let's say it's a polynomial. Take derivative of it, we get a lower degree polynomial. You can't possibly get a matrix out of that!

Answer (score 4):

I think the key point is to understand the meaning of the derivative in this context where $f:\mathbb R^{m \times n} \to \mathbb R$.

My favorite way to think about the gradient of a function $f:\mathbb R^{m \times n} \to \mathbb R$ is

$$\tag{1} f(B + \Delta B) \approx f(B) + \langle \nabla f(B), \Delta B\rangle.$$
 In this equation, $\Delta B$ is a matrix (it is added to $B$, after all), and $\nabla f(B)$ is also a **matrix** (otherwise we could not take the inner product of $\nabla f(B)$ and $\Delta B$).

By the way, what is the inner product we are using here? It is the usual matrix inner product 
$$\langle C,B \rangle = \text{Tr}(C^T B),$$ which is equivalent to just reshaping the matrices $B$ and $C$ into vectors and then taking the dot product of the resulting vectors.

In this specific problem, we have 
$$f(B) =  \text{Tr}(AB) = \langle A^T, B \rangle.$$
Note that
\begin{align}
f(B + \Delta B) &=  \langle A^T, B + \Delta B \rangle \\
&= \underbrace{\langle A^T, B \rangle}_{f(B)} + \langle A^T, \Delta B \rangle.
\end{align}
Comparing this with equation (1), we see that
$$
\nabla f(B) = A^T.
$$

Comment: Yes, this is using $f'(x)= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$, but what's wrong with my logic that $\frac{d}{dB}[tr(AB)]$ is to first take trace, which ends up as a sum of terms, then take derivative. But, no matter what, you don't end up with a matrix. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: @user13985 "no matter what, you don't end up with a matrix" Let me ask you a warm-up question: suppose that $f:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ is defined by $f(\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{bmatrix}) = a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 + a_3 x_3$. Then what is $\nabla f(x)$?

Comment: Ha, you have a good point. I think it's leading somewhere! I guess the key is Jacobian here, which does the partial derivative.

Comment: Am I getting this right?

$$AB= 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}b_{11} + a_{12}b_{21} + a_{13}b_{31} & a_{11}b_{11} + a_{12}b_{21} + a_{13}b_{31} \\
a_{21}b_{11} + a_{22}b_{21} + a_{23}b_{31} & a_{21}b_{12} + a_{22}b_{22} + a_{23}b_{32}
\end{bmatrix} $$


$$tr(AB)= a_{11}b_{11} + a_{12}b_{21} + a_{13}b_{31} + a_{22}b_{21} + a_{22}b_{22} + a_{23}b_{32}$$

Comment: (Continued from last comment)
We have element-wise partial derivative as, 
$$\frac{\partial tr(AB)}{a_{ij}} = b_{ji}$$

Matrix-wise it is, 
$$\frac{dAB}{dA}= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial tr(AB)}{\partial a_{11}} & \frac{\partial tr(AB)}{\partial a_{12}} & \frac{\partial tr(AB)}{\partial a_{13}} \\
\frac{\partial tr(AB)}{\partial a_{21}} & \frac{\partial tr(AB)}{\partial a_{22}} & \frac{\partial tr(AB)}{\partial a_{23}} 
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{11} & b_{12} & b_{13} \\ b_{21} & b_{22} & b_{23} 
\end{bmatrix} =
B^T
$$

Comment: Without using the definition of limit, this is my approach. Is this right?

Comment: @user13985 Yeah, I think that's right. If we're being very careful, we should be sure that the quantity $\frac{df}{dA}$ has been defined in the case where $f:\mathbb R^{m \times n} \to \mathbb R$. But assuming that the quantity $\frac{df}{dA}$ has been defined in a reasonable way, your work is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are very helpful

Answer (score 3):

First, if $A$ is a matrix $m\times n$, then $B$ has to be a $n\times m$ matrix (otherwise it doesn't make sense to talk about $tr(AB)$.)

Now, you can see $B\mapsto tr(AB)$ as a function from  $f:\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}\to \mathbb{R}$ and $\frac{d}{dB}[tr(AB)]$ will be the usual gradient of $f$. This gradient is expected to be some "vector" in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, hence it may be $A^T$.

The mistake is that you are claiming that $\frac{d}{dB}[tr AB]=tr[A\frac{d}{dB}B]$ this doesn't make sense, the one in the left is a "vector"(matrix), while the one in the right is a constant as you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, I think you get what I am asking. So, the trace and derivative are not commutative? If not, $\frac{d}{dB}[tr AB]$ means, first calculate the trace, then take derivative. So, $tr(AB)$ is a sum of multiple terms, but that's still not a matrix!

Comment: @user13985 No, I just showed you that $\frac{d}{dB}[tr(AB)]$ is a vector because it's a gradient.